# Deployment target is 8.0,Will it get installed in iOS 7 devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, xcode7

I have set my project's deployment target to iOS 8.0,but using the development certificate when i am trying to make a build on a iOS 7 device,it is getting installed.Should it be like that?I do not want to give support to iOS 7 when i will finally put my app in Appstore.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set Deployment Target to iOS 8.0 in both **Target** and **Project**?

If not then try to do that and then again try to install app in iOS 7.0 device.

I have attached screen shots for you and are as below.

I hope this will help you.

1.In Project set Deployment target to iOS 8.0.

[image: Project Image]

2.In Target set Deployment target to iOS 8.0.

[image]